# Setting default response headers in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, mean-stack

I'm working on a small app running on the MEAN stack, and have hit an annoying snag: My backend app (Node with [Express](http://expressjs.com/)) is running at `http://localhost:3000` and working just fine, but my frontend client app (Javascript with AngularJS) is running at `http://localhost:8000`, which means requests sent from Angular are received and responded to, but are rejected once they arrive because they're interpreted as coming from a different origin.

I was able to fix this with relatively little drama, by making my 'show me all the stuff' method look something like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  Region.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if(!err) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
      res.json(200, { regions: docs });
    } else {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
      res.json(500, { message: err });
    }
  });
}
```

The `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');` line is the one that I added to tell the browser it was fine to accept the response and stop bothering me about it; the problem now is that I have to add this stupid line to every single response that's sent from anywhere, and I'm convinced I must be missing some way to just change the default headers to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` entry forever.

In a perfect world, I'd be able to flip this on and off based on what environment the code was being executed in, but I'd totally settle for a code block in app.js that I could at least remove one time instead of trying to track down 75 instances of `res.setHeader`. I figure there must be a way to change the `.json` method hiding behind `res` at its base, but the docs don't offer any insight into how I might do that, not to mention whether it's a terrible idea. Any thoughts?

***edit***

I thought (as was suggested) that [configuring application-level middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application) was the key. Here's the code that I added to my app.js file:

```
// allow CORS:
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
  next();
});
```

This, however, yielded the same error ("No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.") as before.

Comment: This is what `app.use()` is for to install a middleware handler that gets to see/modify all requests.

Comment: I have a feeling that I'm close, but the middleware I'm registering doesn't seem to be doing anything (see the edit to my question); I added some debugging output to see when it was being executed, but it never popped up in the console. I was optimistic about [the "setHeaders" option in the built-in middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in), but it's only for the static resources and I can't find a corresponding third-party one that handles... everything else.

Comment: It looks like you might also have to set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.  See http://jonathanmh.com/how-to-enable-cors-in-express-js-node-js/

Comment: Try the npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors it's pretty solid

Comment: @jfriend00: If I use the original, repetitive way of setting the headers, it works with or without `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

@jusynth: The "cors" packaged WORKED! At first, it failed like the other half-dozen packages I've tried, but moving `app.use(cors());` from the bottom of the list of `app.use(foo)` entries to the top of the list fixed it all. No idea why. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one as a middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
  next();
});
```

Comment: is this safe for production use-cases?

Comment: you can use exact IP for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header more security and can delete `X-Requested-With` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.Otherwise, it's oK

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone seeing this, using `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will result in an error for requests that use credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue and tried the same snippet above. It did the trick.

```js
// allow CORS:
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000')
  next()
})
```

**IMPORTANT:** I had to place it **above all other** `app.use(xyz)` entries, just like @rev_bird mentioned he did with the CORS module. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a common middleware using .use() or can use npm packages like  [express-interceptor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-interceptor) also to intercept the response

Comment: Gah, I hate to un-mark this as the answer, but I realized once I approved this one that I'd forgotten to restart the server. I added my snippet above so you can see what got added, but it didn't actually work.